# Building a preconditioned iterative method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider a preconditioned iterative method of least residuals for solving a system of linear equations $Ax=b$ with positive definite matrix $A$:
$$
\tag{1}
r_n = b - A x_n; \\
\alpha_n = \frac{(A M^{-1} r_n, r_n)}{(A M^{-1} r_n, A M^{-1} r_n)}; \\
x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha_n M^{-1} r_n.
$$

Its non-preconditioned version (when $M = E$) looks like this:
$$
\tag{2}
r_n = b - A x_n; \\
\alpha_n = \frac{(A r_n, r_n)}{(A r_n, A r_n)}; \\
x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha_n r_n.
$$

Let's write out an algorithm (2) for the system $A' x = b'$, where $A' = M^{-1} A$, $b' = M^{-1} b$:
$$
\tag{3}
r'_n = b' - A' x_n = M^{-1} (b - A x_n) = M^{-1} r_n; \\
\alpha_n = \frac{(A' r'_n, r'_n)}{(A' r'_n, A' r'_n)} = \frac{(M^{-1} A M^{-1} r_n, M^{-1} r_n)}{(M^{-1} A M^{-1} r_n, M^{-1} A M^{-1} r_n)}; \\
x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha_n r'_n = x_n - \alpha_n M^{-1} r_n.
$$

It can be seen that the formulas for $\alpha_n$ in (1) and in (3) differ. This suggests that there is a mistake somewhere in the reasoning, but I can't find it. Where am I wrong?

Perhaps there are no errors. But then equality
$$\frac{(M^{-1} x, M^{-1} y)}{(M^{-1} z, M^{-1} w)} = \frac{(x, y)}{(z, w)}$$
must be satisfied, but I don't understand how to prove it.

Some may have a question why I built (3) from (2) if I already had the algorithm (1) obtained in some way. The answer is simple: I wanted to make sure that the algorithm (1) was constructed correctly by constructing it in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the update formula: it should be $x_{n+1} = x_n+\alpha_n r_n$ when the residual is defined with $x_n$ having the negative sign.

Otherwise, your reasoning is almost correct, except that in $(3)$ you wrote an algorithm for the *left* preconditioned system:
$$
M^{-1}Ax = M^{-1}b
$$

On the other hand, the formula in $(1)$ is for *right* preconditioned system:
$$
AM^{-1}Mx = b
$$

You can derive the formula with similar substition of variables, this time with $A'=AM^{-1}$ and $x'=Mx$. In this case, $r_n$ is unchanged, as
$$
\begin{aligned}
r_n &= b - A'x' \\
    &= b - AM^{-1}Mx \\
    &= b - Ax
\end{aligned}
$$
On the other hand, the step multiplier is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_n &= {(A'r_n,r_n)\over(A'r_n,A'r_n)} \\
         &= {(AM^{-1}r_n,r_n)\over(AM^{-1}r_n,AM^{-1}r_n)}
\end{aligned}
$$
while the update formula is
$$
\begin{aligned}
x'_{n+1} &= x'_n + \alpha_nr_n \\
Mx_{n+1} &= Mx_n + \alpha_nr_n \\
\therefore x_{n+1} &=  x_n + \alpha_nM^{-1}r_n \\
\end{aligned}
$$